# CakePHP validates() odd array return (1,2) value behaviour

Tags: arrays, validation, cakephp, controller

My validation is working just fine, but seemingly randomly, the retured values are not my model set validation errors, and nothing should be triggering the error, but a "1" or "2" is returned..

Even if all field data is valid, I sometimes get a return value in my array of "1" or "2"...

Here is my validation in my controller:

```
 if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
        if ($this->Plan->validates()) {
            $this->Plan->set($this->data);
            $errors = $this->Plan->invalidFields();
            $this->set('errors', $errors);
        } else {
            $this->Plan->set($this->data);
        }
 }
```

And here is my model validation:

```
        'ApplicantAge'   => array(
array('rule'=> array('maxLength', 3),
      'message' => 'Applicant Age cannot be longer than 3 digits.'),
      'last' => true,
array('rule'    => array('range', -1, 120),
      'message' => 'Applicant Age cannot exceed 120.'),
      'last' => true,
array('rule'    => 'numeric',
      'message' => 'Applicant Age must be a valid age.'),
      'last' => true,
),
    'SpouseAge'      => array(
array('allowEmpty' => true),
        'last' => true,
array('rule'    => array('maxLength', 3),
      'message' => 'Spouse Age cannot be longer than 3 digits.'),
      'last' => true,
array('rule'    => array('range', -1, 120),
      'message' => 'Spouse Age cannot exceed 120.'),
      'last' => true,
array('rule' => 'numeric',
      'message' => 'Spouse Age must be numeric.'),
      'last' => true,
),
    'NumberChildren' => array(
array('allowEmpty' => true),
      'last' => true,
array('rule'    => array('range', -1, 20),
      'message' => 'Number of Children cannot exceed 20.'),
      'last' => true,
array('rule'    => 'numeric',
      'message' => 'Number of Children must be numeric.'),
      'last' => true,
),
    'ZipCode' => array(
array('rule'    => array('postal', null, 'us'),
      'message' => 'Zip Code format must be valid. Example: 97756'),
      'last' => true,
array('rule'    => array('minLength', 5),
      'rule'    => array('maxLength', 5),
      'message' => 'Zip Code must be 5 digits.'),
      'last' => true
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be setting the data in the model before validating it?

```
if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
    $this->Plan->set($this->data);
    if ($this->Plan->validates()) {
        //do something since data validates
    } else {
        $errors = $this->Plan->invalidFields();
        $this->set('errors', $errors);
    }
}
```

I know that you said it was random, but are you able to find any consistency in the error? You may be able to return the values for $this->data and the Plan model itself to make sure that the information is correct there as well. It may be that the validator is getting bad data to begin with.